# TypeScript function overloading with passing a variable

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm trying to use TypeScript function overloading:

```
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: EntityWithTranslations): T;
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: null): {};

function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: EntityWithTranslations | null): T | {} {
  // do smth and return T or {}
}
```

It works if I call it these ways:

```
useEntityTranslation<ProductTranslation>(product); // EntityWithTranslations type
useEntityTranslation<ProductTranslation>(null);
```

But if product is of type `EntityWithTranslations | null` (it's in React component: null until an entity is retrieved from api)

```
useEntityTranslation<ProductTranslation>(product); // EntityWithTranslations | null
```

TypeScript throws an error `No overload matches this call`.

It's because the type `EntityWithTranslations | null` is not assignable to any of the two overloads.

But how can I make it understandable for TypeScript?

**UPDATE**:

The problem also is I can't use a received value as a known type

```
const translation = useEntityTranslation<ProductTranslation>(product);
translation.name // name doesn't exist in {}
```

My workaround is to add one more overload:

```
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: EntityWithTranslations | null): { [name: string]: any }
```

I use `translation` if `product` isn't null, so I'm sure `translation` is of type `ProductTranslation`.

Not awesome (`translation.name -> any`) but at least works

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, TypeScript does not resolve overloads by allowing unions of arguments from different call signatures.  There is a longstanding open suggestion, [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107), asking for this to happen, but for now it is not part of the language.

The easiest way to deal with this for a small number of call signatures is to add new call signatures corresponding to each union of arguments you want to support.  In your case, you could add a single overload signature that happens to be the same as your implementation signature:

```
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: EntityWithTranslations): T;
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: null): {};
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity: EntityWithTranslations | null): T | {};

function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(
  entity: EntityWithTranslations | null
): T | {} {
  // do smth and return T or {}
  return null!;
}
```

And then it will work the way you want:

```
useEntityTranslation<ProductTranslation>(Math.random() < 0.5 ? product : null); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxk4ArmBgFzwCiKGAlhgJ4DqtAFgCoxTrQ2poDcAKAEB6YfADyANxAwISKMDRCAZgRTFqqeATQhKNeu05pumlAB5W8EAA8MIFIvhGuUHigB8ACgcG6ZfVpGFhcTNzM0AEoyVkFVdXdtXUDDDld3S2s7BydQ01RvXyCyFAIICGj4AG8AXzi1DS0dPSogvPDUTNt7RzRnNLD3Qtb6AJHgjDYB-PR4AB94UvLKqwXa+oSzJJa-doyrbpy+vbNhvzG-JkmT3nnFsoqYu9rqgXh4UXhgJHg0AFtJvBOMB4HAMAQYChnPAkDBqjU3qCQODIfdygBCQQIgTNFJ0G4WAAKeEIxAJ3lw+CIGEiglx4wJ5mJVLJ0w6ni8SwqdOSDLZGWZpIw5K8AFk3MwAHRpb5-LyReDmeAABklAFZ4AB+HAk6nwEoPWkfMRIADWUDoQhEYgAwqhgLQzFAIPAvAB3FiICEwOjUFAAc0iQmQ6Cw9L8Nu9dHgAF5FQdsr1+sYZt4FTGPIjzABVLI9Jx4q5TFPsvoLLlnYrwbOVXOHJOFkL8iJa6FkF4Z17vd5giFQrmYxHYkOYbZ4wXUgmxsfjSMwH1M3WsktDeWCEdYbDT8NBCfL9JmLyUoVGz574XN1ACDeLbe8vzngmcw18Y3w6+8TdQuM7+iPy8oGKErSsCSBygqSqqhq2rHnqBrLK+nwvAs-4rmYVqiJ89DYCASh+vYMDKFAYAIFOVSIjYZCYDAfr+liAj4TIREkRQ4xFgSfTke8-j3H8ABGMj0QxVBMcRCCoQeWj1rkAFdvAABeVEYDRAb0UAA)

Comment: Thanks for your extended reply. But there is a new problem. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is that you want

```
function useEntityTranslation<T extends Translation>(entity?:EntityWithTranslations): T | {}
```

Comment: I don't think I can use a question mark and initializer in arguments